# Get count of user documents in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

How can I get the list of all users and the number of Google Documents they have in Google Apps using Google Script?

Regards

Comment: "all users"? of your domain or what?

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to list the users and the number of docs, you can use the reports API for Drive activity: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-docs.

Getting all users uses a similar service, and is practically written for you: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory.

Comment: The Google Docs User Metrics is now depreciated