# Efficiently get total count of all Google documents in a user's Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-app-maker

In the admin console, you can see the total number of Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Drawings a user has. This number updates instantly when native Google files are added to a user's Drive.

[image: screenshot of user data counts in the admin console]

The Gmail API and the Drive API both have easy ways to get the total storage used in GBs - but native Google Drive file types like Sheets, Slides, and Docs don't count toward a users' storage quota, so a user with zero non-Google files and hundreds of Google Docs files would appear to have an empty Drive if you only checked the size of the account in GBs.

I haven't found an easy way to get the total number of documents for a user, other than doing a search, and that can be performance-intensive for large numbers of users. I'm using the App Script API from an App Maker project if that matters.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725883/get-count-of-user-documents-in-google-drive) references an API that no longer exists.

Comment: Where's the code you've already tried? The Apps Script [`AdminReports`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports) client library most certainly still exists, btw.

Comment: `AdminReports` only gets the last ~6 months of data https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566?hl=en

Comment: Go ahead and show the app script from your app maker project.

Comment: @Ian and? You said "this answer references an API no longer exists," yet `AdminReports` clearly does still exist, and the other APIs have clearly identified successors.

Comment: Also consider: if you need to exhaustively count every single `$mimeType` in a user's Google Drive... then use the Drive REST API to do that. It is absolutely capable of doing that. Maybe you don't really need to though--maybe you can avoid that query for any accounts that have associated data in the last 6 months ("hey, this account's not empty!"). Maybe you run that query script once, store the result, and then start storing reports so you have more than 6mo of them. PS: how "performance-intensive" is it, per user? Where's your metric?

Comment: @tehhowch `AdminReports` does still exist but only gets data from the last 6 months - there's no command in the `AdminReports` API to get the total number of docs owned that I can find.The APIs defined as successors only have added/removed/delta in a given timeframe as options for Docs owned.

Comment: For your second comment I think the combination of both may be the best way to go - and I mean "performance intensive" in time to perform - this will need to run for tens of thousands of users and I'm concerned about the time querying each Drive will take to run